# How to properly remove a character from a char array (with or without converting to a string)?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

*Sorry in advance for any possible duplicate question. I have been Googling a solution for my compiler error, for a week now, tried different workarounds from various answers around here, yet I keep getting some errors.*

I am currently learning C++, trying to build a program that does basic stuff like vowel/consonant count, letter removal etc. Everything works fine until I get to the *custom letter* removal part. Basically, it's near impossible to do that using character functions (according to my knowledge), while converting to a string seems to spawn other kinds of errors.

Here is the code fragment where I keep getting errors:

```
if (strcmp (service, key4) ==0)
{
string str(s);

cout<<endl<<"Please insert the letter you would like removed from your "<<phrasal<<":"<<endl;

cin>>letterToRemove;

s.erase(remove(s.begin(), s.end(),letterToRemove), s.end());

cout<<endl<<s<< "\n"<<endl;
}
```

and here are initialized variable I used:

```
int main()

{
char s[1000], phrasal[10], service[50], key1[] = "1", key2[] = "2", key3[] = "3", key4[] = "4", key5[] = "5", key6[] = "6", key0[] = "0", *p, letterToRemove;

int vowel=0, vowel2=0, consonant=0, consonant2=0, b, i, j, k, phrase=0, minusOne, letter, idxToDel;

void pop_back();

char *s_bin;
```

As you can see, the original **'s'** is a char array. In the first code sample I have tried converting it into a string array (*string str(s)*), but that results in the following compiling errors:

- error: request for member 'erase' in 's', which is of non-class type 'char[1000]'
- error: request for member 'begin' in 's', which is of non-class type 'char[1000]'
- error: request for member 'end' in 's', which is of non-class type 'char[1000]'
- error: request for member 'end' in 's', which is of non-class type 'char[1000]'

The other workaround I've tried was this:

```
if(strcmp(service, key4)==0)

{std::string s(s);

cout<<endl<<"Please insert the letter you would like removed from your "<<phrasal<<":"<<endl;

cin>>letterToRemove;

s.erase(remove(s.begin(), s.end(),letterToRemove), s.end());

cout<<endl<<s<< "\n"<<endl;
}
```

Now here's the funny part, I get no errors whatsoever for this one, but the debug crashes as soon as I select the *custom letter removal* feature. Here's what it says:

["terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create
         This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzILv.png)

Any help would be much appreciated, stuck at this one for a week now!

*P.S. Is it okay if I or a moderator deletes this question after it's been answered? I'm quite sure I'm not the first one who asks this, but, as before-hand mentioned, I keep getting these errors, even after following answers from similar questions.*

Comment: Are you coding in C or C++? Is `s` a string? If you are coding in C++ and `s` is a string, then why don't use `std::string` to begin with?

Comment: no it's not ok to ask a question, get the answer and then delete the question. We are a community here and your question and answers could help others.

Comment: As for your errors, try using e.g. `str.erase(...)` instead.

Comment: `std::string s(s);` What do you think this does? It's UB because you use the value of an uninitialized object (ironically in an attempt to initialize that object).

Comment: The first failure about begin and end... Raw arrays cannot be treated as containers, so you can't std::begin() or std::end() them. Also, you seem to be constructing a std::string "s" with "s": what's that supposed to do?. You should be constructing it with the original string ("prhasal", I assume?").

Comment: @JoachimPileborg C++.  's' was initially a char, as shown in the second code fragment (char s[1000]). I have previously read that a solution for this would be converting the char array into a string array, yet that still gives errors, as above.

Comment: @Teo If you program in `C++` then do so. Use `std::string` from the begging.

Comment: @bolov Thank you for the heads-up, my intention is just not to flood the archive.   I've tried doing that aswell, but my code previously uses character functions such as strcpy and strcmp, I would have to rewrite 113 lines of code, so I was curious if there is any way of making it work by editing this portion

Comment: @Teo Good questions are valued. So when you ask good questions you are actually contributing here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a char array you have to use
 [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) instead of `erase`, and insert the null-terminator manually:

```
auto newEnd = std::remove(std::begin(s), std::end(s), letterToRemove);
*newEnd = '\0';
```

Comment: Thank you. Both yours and @baddger964 's answers seems to have solved this problem. However, what exactly happens to the _char s[ ]_ array after I have converted it using _string str(s)_ ? My code consists of some loops that will make it go back to certain points, where the operator is required to insert a word/phrase based on the _cin.getline_ format (to be as detailed as possible, you have to insert a sentence which equals '_cin.getline(service, 50)_' ; depending on your input, the standard will have to apply some **char** functions to the **s** array). Thank you for your time.

Comment: _"what exactly happens to the char s[ ] array after I have converted it using string str(s) ?"_ — Nothing. The characters are copied into the `std::string` object, and the array is left untouched.

Comment: Thanks @tuple_cat, that's great!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a generic array, that may or may not have decayed to a pointer, and you have the number of elements in the array but no other terminator (i.e. it's not a C-style zero-terminated string), then here's a solution:

First I want to you think abut how the array looks in memory. For example if we have an array of characters

```
char array[X] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ... };
```

This array will look like this in memory

```
+---+---+---+---+-----+
| A | B | C | D | ... |
+---+---+---+---+-----+
```

If you wanted to remove the letter `'B'` from that array you find the position of the letter, then you copy the next letter (`'C'`) into its place, and the next next letter (`'D'`) into the next letter place, etc.

You can of course do this using a single loop:

```
size_t index_to_remove = 1;  // The index of 'B'
for (size_t i = index_to_remove = 1; i < element_count - 1; ++i)
    array[i] = array[i + 1];
```

The above loop is simple, easy to figure out, and easy to step through in a debugger. It is also not very effective, especially if the array is large.

All the above copying can actually be done using a single call to the [`memmove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) function:

```
memmove(&array[index_to_remove],
        &array[index_to_remove + 1],
        element_count - index_to_remove - 1);
```

The above call will basically do the same as our loop above but in a more efficient and optimized way.

Using either of the above methods, the loop or the `memmove` call, will leave the array like this:

```
+---+---+---+-----+
| A | C | D | ... |
+---+---+---+-----+
```

***Important note:*** Remember to change `element_count` after you "removed" the character, so it reflects the new size.

Comment: Yep, that's how it works indeed, but for my code you do not have an already known position for the element you want removed; the operator inputs a number/letter and the program would have to search for that element in the string array... which brings it to another questioning: what algorithm should I apply after the **strchr** function, that will basically do what you pinpointed in your example above?   Thanks for the highly detailed answer, though, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Teo If you are using `strchr`, or any other C string function on this array, then it *is* a string and you should really be using `std::string`.

Comment: @Teo As for your question in the comment, you can actually subtract two (related) pointers to get the difference. If you subtract `s` from the (non-null) pointer you get from `strchr` you get an offset that can be used as an index. Or you use the result from `strchr` directly in the call to `memmove`.

Answer (score 0):

For your first workaround :

```
string str(s);
```

This statement declare a string named `str` and is content is initialized with the content of `s`

This statement as no effect on you object  `s`

So you need to call `str.erase()` not `s.erase()`

Comment: Thank you, this has proven useful!