# What does strcpy(s+i, s+i+1) mean?

Tags: c++, string

I have this piece of code:

```cpp
int i = 0;
char s[12];
strcpy(s,"abracadabra");
cout << strlen(s);
while(i < strlen(s))
{
    if (s[i]=='a') strcpy(s+i, s+i+1);
    else i++;
}
cout << " " << s;
```

But I can't understand why the output is `brcdbr`.

I thought that `s+i` means `s[n+i]` or something like that?

Can someone explain to me how this works?

Comment: It's undefined behavior, because `strcpy` has undefined behavior if the source & destination ranges overlap. As they do here.  It appears the intent is to remove all `'a'` characters from the `char` array, in an inefficient manner.

Comment: Related: [Result of calling strcpy is different than expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546706/result-of-calling-strcpy-is-different-than-expected).

Comment: `s+i` is like `&s[i]`, and `s+i+1` is like `&s[i+1]`.  For user specified overload `operator[]` on a user type, those similarities may not apply.

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal type [man strcpy](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html)

> char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);

> The strcpy() function copies the string pointed to by src,
> including the terminating null byte ('\0'), to the buffer pointed
> to by dest.  **The strings may not overlap**, and the destination
> string dest must be large enough to receive the copy.  Beware of
> buffer overruns!  (See BUGS.)

So you are copying all bytes from your string,

- from src: index i + 1 (the next letter after 'a') to '\0'
- to dest: index i (letter 'a') to '\0'

NB: As stated in the comments it is a very inefficient way and undefined behavior to get rid of the 'a', but I guess you came here for the explanation about `s+i`, it means `&s[i]` or even `&i[s]`.

Read more about "Pointer arithmetic"

If you want an efficient way take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122385/how-to-properly-remove-a-character-from-a-char-array-with-or-without-converting)

Comment: *"The strings may not overlap"* this is important. As Eljay mentioned in the comments this is undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes I bolded it. However his question is mostly about pointer arithmetic and not so much about the very bad usage of strcpy even though it is worth pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

> *Can someone explain to me how this works?*

it doesn't work, the behavior of the program is [undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Nothing meaningful can be said about the outcome (even if it *looks* correct in some specific case).

For example, here on [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/o3MT7n) the output is not `brcdbr` but `brcdrr`.

That's because it's illegal to invoke `strcpy` with overlapping source and destination pointers:

> **C11 §7.24.2.3 The strcpy function**
>
> The strcpy function copies the string pointed to by s2 (including the
> terminating null character) into the array pointed to by s1. **If
> copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is
> undefined.**

(note: C++ [inherits](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/cstring.syn#1) C rules for C standard library functions)

Anyway, if you just wanted to know the intention behind `strcpy(s+i, s+i+1)`, in C++ expressions an array automatically *decays* to a pointer. So `char s[12]` becomes `char* s`. Then the expression `s+i` becomes pointer arithmetic - taking an address of `i`<sup>th</sup> element pointed-to by `s`. It is equivalent to writing `&s[i]`, i.e. taking an address of `i`<sup>th</sup> element in `s`. The same applies to `s+i+1` - it evaluates to a pointer to the `i+1`<sup>th</sup> element in `s`. The intention of the `strcpy` call was to copy the remainder of the string *after* `a` to the memory are *starting* at `a`, i.e. to *shift* the remaining characters forward by one, thus overwriting the `a`.

A better way in C++ would be to use `std::string` and the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) to remove the characters `a` from the string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s = "abracadabra";
    s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), 'a'), s.end());
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Prints:

```
brcdbr
```